# Count Duplicates and show count for a single column by group

Tags: mysql

I am trying to retrieve a list of inventory items and group them together. So far the query I have works wonderfully but now I want to add another column to the table that is shown to the user. The `current_inventory` table  has five columns I am interested in `Model`, `ModelType`, `ModelDoor`, `NoFaucet` and `Tested`. My current query is:

```
SELECT Model, ModelType, ModelDoor, NoFaucet, COUNT(*) AS count 
FROM current_inventory 
GROUP BY Model, ModelType, ModelDoor, NoFaucet'
```

Which will show the amount of duplicates in the `current_inventory` table and show how many of each product is in stock at the moment. Now what I would like to do is make use of the `Tested` column and show how many of the products currently in stock have been tested. So for example if my table looks like this:

```
+-------+-----------+-----------+----------+--------+
| Model | ModelType | ModelDoor | NoFaucet | Tested |
+-------+-----------+-----------+----------+--------+
| Epic  | Soaking   | Left      |        0 |      1 |
| Epic  | Soaking   | Left      |        0 |      0 |
| Zebra | Whirlpool | Right     |        1 |      0 |
+-------+-----------+-----------+----------+--------+
```

When the query is run and output to the user it should read like this:

```
+-------+-----------+-----------+----------+--------+--------------+
| Model | ModelType | ModelDoor | NoFaucet | Tested | CurrentStock |
+-------+-----------+-----------+----------+--------+--------------+
| Epic  | Soaking   | Left      | No       |      1 |            2 |
| Zebra | Whirlpool | Right     | Yes      |      0 |            1 |
+-------+-----------+-----------+----------+--------+--------------+
```

Notice that there are two `Epic` products in stock and out of those two, one has been tested. I hope this makes sense. Am I able to accomplish this in a single query by modifying my existing one? I have tried adding the `Testing` column to the current query but it will show them as separate products which is not what I want.

EDIT: I should make it clear that the `1` and `0` in the `Tested` and `NoFaucet` columns are boolean values not an actual count.

UPDATE: Thanks to the comment below I was able to re-write the query and it worked. The updated Query is below:

```
SELECT Model, ModelType, ModelDoor, NoFaucet, COUNT(*) AS count,
SUM(Tested)
FROM current_inventory 
GROUP BY Model, ModelType, ModelDoor, NoFaucet'
```

Comment: @eggyal thank you I was able to successfully figure out the query based on your comment.